# Entropy of vaporization and relation to heat capacity at constant pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Uni student here in physical chemistry and in thermodynamics we are discussing entropy at the moment. We were tasked to find $ \Delta S_{vap}$ at $T_{2}$ given a $ \Delta S_{vap}$ at $T_{1}$. Items we were also given:
$$
\Delta H_{vap}(T1), \Delta S_{vap}(T1), C_{p,m}(g), \text{and} C_{p,m}(l)
$$

I did get the right answer from some help from an older classmate, though they aren't sure of why its correct. They did:
$$
\Delta S_{vap}(T2) = \Delta S_{vap}(T1) + \Delta C_{p.m}\cdot ln(\frac{T2}{T1})
$$
I'm aware of the $ln\frac{T2}{T1}$ stemming from the identity $\Delta S = \int_{T1}^{T2}(\frac{C}{T})dT$ but where does the $\Delta C_{p,m}$ come from? Can't find this in my P-chem textbook, and google searches didn't yield me anything. Thanks!

Edit: To clarify, the $\Delta C_{p,m}$ referred to $C_{p,m}(g)-C_{p,m}(l)$ sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edit to address an ambiguity pointed out by Chet: Since I know what relation you're trying to achieve, I know that you mean that $T_1$ is the boiling temperature at the given conditions, i.e., that vaporization is reversible at $T_1$ but not at $T_2\neq T_1$. The problem statement should make this clear, as other answers are possible if one assumes that the surroundings are adjusted such that vaporization is also reversible at $T_2$, for example.)

So we know $\Delta S_{\mathrm{vap},T_1}$, referring to the entropy change for reversible vaporization at temperature $T_1$ (system and surroundings); in other words, the boiling temperature is $T_1$. If I'm instead at temperature $T_2$, vaporization is no longer reversible under the original conditions; this is going to screw up my $\Delta S$ model because entropy will be generated as well as transferred.

Instead, let me take a reversible, non-entropy-generating path by conceptually changing the material temperature reversibly from $T_2$ to $T_1$ (through successive contact with an infinite number of large thermal reservoirs at temperatures within that range), then performing reversible vaporization, and then bringing the vapor reversibly back from temperature $T_1$ to $T_2$. (Maybe you see where this is going.) The outcome is the same, but now the path for the system is reversible.

Adding up the entropy changes for one phase change and two constant-pressure heating and cooling processes, I obtain

\begin{align}\Delta S_{\mathrm{vap},T_2}&=C_{P,\mathrm{condensed\,phase}}\ln\left(\frac{T_1}{T_2}\right)+\Delta S_{\mathrm{vap},T_1}+C_{P,\mathrm{vapor}}\ln\left(\frac{T_2}{T_1}\right)\\
&=\Delta S_{\mathrm{vap},T_1}+(C_{P,\mathrm{vapor}}-C_{P,\mathrm{condensed\,phase}})\ln\left(\frac{T_2}{T_1}\right).\end{align}

Thus, we end up with a difference in heat capacities because we conceptually take a trip to $T_2$ as one phase and come back as another phase. Does this make sense?

Comment: thank you!!! I think this is it

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers is correct.  The correct answer for $\Delta S_{vap}(T_2)$ is $$\Delta S_{vap}(T_2)=\frac{\Delta H_{vap}(T_2)}{T_2}$$From Hess' Law, $$\Delta H_{vap}(T_2)=-\int_{T_1}^{T_2}{C_{p, liquid}dT}+\Delta H_{vap}(T_1)+\int_{T_1}^{T_2}{C_{p, vap}dT}$$Assuming constant heat capacities of the liquid and vapor (and ideal gas behavior of the vapor), this becomes:  $$\Delta H_{vap}(T_2)=\Delta H_{vap}(T_1)+\Delta C_{p,m}(T_2-T_1)$$Dividing this by $T_2$ gives:$$\Delta S_{vap}(T_2)=\Delta S_{vap}(T_1)\frac{T_1}{T_2}+\Delta C_{p,m}\left(1-\frac{T_1}{T_2}\right)$$

The other answers don't take into account the effect of pressure on the entropy of the vapor.

Comment: You've added the additional assumption that the phase change at $T_2$ is reversible and thus obtained a different result. My answer reviews the standard derivation for the relation being sought; see [here](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~vnicule/Lecture%208%20Part%20IV%20Entropy.pdf) (the section on "Phase changes under non-equilibrium conditions"), for example.

Comment: [Another example specifically on the entropy of vaporization](https://lavelle.chem.ucla.edu/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27087).

Comment: @chemomechanics. The problem statement clearly implies to me that the entropy change at T2 is reversible

Answer (score -1):

First a couple of definitions:

$dU = TdS \Rightarrow dS = dU/T$

$ U = ΔCp.m * T \Rightarrow dU = ΔCp.m * dT$

Then the derivation:

$\Delta S = S(T_2)-S(T_1)= \int_{T_1}^{T_2} dS = \int_{T_1}^{T_2} 1/T  dU = \int_{T_1}^{T_2} ΔCp.m/T  dT = ΔCp.m*ln(T_2/T_1)$

Comment: "$ U = ΔCp.m * T $" is not an accurate definition. I don't see how this aims to answer the question except to rearrange the symbols (near-meaninglessly).

Comment: Right, the ΔCp.m is not defined in the question.  I'm assuming that ΔCp.m is ΔCp * m or a similar definition of the total energy change per K.